# Geometrically reduced algebraic extension of a field

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field.
Let $A$ be a commutative algebra over $k$.
We say $A$ is geometrically reduced over $k$ if $A\otimes_k k'$ is reduced for every extension $k'$ of $k$.

Let $K$ be an algebraic extension of $k$.
It is well-known that $K$ is geometrically reduced over $k$ if $K$ is separable over $k$.
Conversely suppose $K$ is geometrically reduced over $k$.
$K$ is separable over $k$?

Comment: If the extension $\,K/k\,$ is infinite then yes, as can be checked  in this very nice paper: http://tinyurl.com/amj3rzw . In fact, it is just definition.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Doesn't theorem 1.2 say just that for *finite* extensions?

Comment: Well, but there's a condition on non-zero nilpotent elements there, @tomasz

Comment: @DonAntonio: I don't understand. The condition means exactly the same as being geometrically reduces, no?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here, @tomasz, but theorem 1.2 requires that tensor product to have no non-zero nilpotent elements.

Comment: @DonAntonio: The theorem states that a finite extension is separable iff it is geometrically reduced. How could it assume geometrical reduction in the first place?

Comment: Oh, I see my confusion now: yes, reduced = no non-zero nilpotent elements. Ok.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks. Theorem 1.2 of the paper treats finite extensions, but the infinite extension case follows trivially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $K_0$ be the separable closure of $k$ in $K$. Let $L$ be any extension of $K_0$. Then 
$$(K\otimes_{K_0} L) \hookrightarrow (K\otimes_{K_0} L)\otimes_{k} K_0 \simeq K\otimes_k L.$$ 
So $K\otimes_{K_0} L$ is reduced.

Let $p\ge 0$ be the characteristic of $k$. We can suppose $p>0$ (otherwise any extension is separable). If $K\neq K_0$, there exists $\alpha\in K\setminus K_0$ such that some power $a=\alpha^{p}\in K_0$. Consider $L=K_0[\alpha]\subseteq K$. Then $L\simeq K_0[X]/(X^p-a)$ and 
$$ K_0[\alpha]\otimes_{K_0} L\simeq K_0[X]/(X^p-a)=K_0[X]/(X-\alpha)^p$$ 
is not reduced. This is a contradiction because on the other hand $K_0[\alpha]\otimes_{K_0} L\subseteq K\otimes_{K_0} L$ must be reduced. So $K=K_0$.